# Adaptive time step for Runge-Kutta method ode45 in deSolve

Tags: r, ode, runge-kutta

I want to use the explicit Runge-Kutta method **ode45** (alias rk45dp7) from the **deSolve** R package in order to solve an ODE problem with variable step size.

According to the deSolve documentation, it is possible to use adaptive or variable time steps for the **[rk](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/deSolve/docs/rk)** solver function with the ode45 method instead of equidistant time steps but I'm at loss how to do this.

The rk funcion is called like this:

```
rk(y, times, func, parms, rtol = 1e-6, atol = 1e-6, verbose = FALSE, tcrit = NULL,
hmin = 0, hmax = NULL, hini = hmax, ynames = TRUE, method = rkMethod("rk45dp7", ... ), 
maxsteps = 5000, dllname = NULL, initfunc = dllname, initpar = parms, rpar = NULL, 
ipar = NULL, nout = 0, outnames = NULL, forcings = NULL, initforc = NULL, fcontrol = 
NULL, events = NULL, ...)
```

with *times* being the vector of times at which explicit estimates for y are desired.

For equdistant time steps with a distance of 0.01 I can write *times* as

```
times <- seq(0, 100, 0.01)
```

Supposing I want to solve the equation for the interval from 0 to 100 how do I define *times* without giving a step size?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you are confusing the parameter `times` here. It **times** at which explicit estimates for y are desired. Maybe reading parameter of `rkMethod('rk45dp7')` should help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two issues here. First, if you want to specify a vector of times with multiple increments, use this (for example):

```
times <- c(seq(0,0.9,0.1),seq(1,10,1))
times
#  [1]  0.0  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7  0.8  0.9  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0 10.0
```

Here, we have [0,1] by 0.1, and [1,10] by 1.

But you don't actually have to do this: the parameter `times=` tells `rk(...)` for which times to report results. An adaptive algorithm will *internally* adjust the time increment to yield accurate results at the times specified in the argument. So for an adaptive algorithm, e.g., `method="rk45dp7"` you don't have to do anything. For a non-adaptive algorithm, for example `method="euler"`, the time increment used by the algorithm is indeed the increment specified in `times=`. You can see the effect of this in this simple example, which integrates the Van der Pol oscillator.

```
y.prime <- function(t,y.vector,b) {    # Van der Pol oscillator
  x <- y.vector[1]
  y <- y.vector[2]
  x.prime <- y
  y.prime <- b*y*(1-x)^2 - x
  return(list(c(x=x.prime,y=y.prime)))
}
h  <- .001                  # time increment
t  <-  seq(0,10,h)          # times to report results
y0 <- c(0.01,0.01)          # initial conditions
euler   <- rk(y0, t,func=y.prime,parms=1,method="euler")
rk45dp7 <- rk(y0, t,func=y.prime,parms=1, method="rk45dp7")
# plot x vs. y
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(euler[,2],euler[,3], type="l",xlab="X",ylab="Y",main=paste("Euler: h =",format(h,digits=3)))
plot(rk45dp7[,2],rk45dp7[,3], type="l",xlab="X",ylab="Y",main=paste("RK45DP7: h =",format(h,digits=3)))
```

Below is a comparison of the results for several values of `h`. Note that with `method="rk45dp7"` the results are stable for `h < 0.5`. This is because `rk45dp7` is internally adjusting the time increment as needed. For `method="euler"` the results do not match `rk45dp7` until `h~0.01`.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your extensive answer! It truly helped me to understand the concept behind adaptive and non-adaptive methods.

Comment: Glad I could be of help.